# Link JSCS to autoformat in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm, jshint, jscs

I'm using JSCS (google) for javascript and also JSHint, However if I autoformat my code with cmd+L it creates a space between function and an opening `(`. Is there anyway to tell the auto format function to obey to the coding guydes from JSCS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just tell it to obey this or that standard code style. But you can configure formatting options in `Settings/Code Style/javascript`. Try Spaces/Before Parentheses options: `'in function declaration'`, `'in function expression'`, `'function call parentheses'`

Comment: thx lena, it was actually the 'In function expression' but that helped me to find the right spot

Answer (score 0):

Editor > Code Style > JavaScript

You can select Manage and import your JSCS file. This should cover the majority of your needs. Note that if you're just selecting Google from the drop down for your guide, you will need to download [Googles JSCS](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/master/presets/google.json) file.